# How to show roles of user discord.js / userinfo command

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a `userinfo` command, and I'm currently stuck on showing roles of the user.

Here is my code:

```
const Discord = module.require('discord.js');
const moment = require('moment');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
    const joinDiscord = moment(user.createdAt).format('llll');
    const joinServer = moment(user.joinedAt).format('llll');
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(user.username + '#' + user.discriminator, user.displayAvatarURL)
        .setDescription(`${user}`)
        .setColor(`RANDOM`)
        .setThumbnail(`${user.displayAvatarURL}`)
        .addField('Joined at:', `${moment.utc(user.joinedAt).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss')}`, true)
        .addField('Status:', user.presence.status, true)
        .addField('Roles:', user.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join(' | '), true)
        .setFooter(`ID: ${user.id}`)
        .setTimestamp();

    message.channel.send({ embed: embed });
    return;
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: 'userinfo'
}
```

I'm getting this error **`TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`** and I don't know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`User.roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) is `undefined` because that property doesn't exist: try using [`GuildMember.roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles) instead:

```
let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member,
  user = member.user;

let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  // ... all the other stuff ...
  .addField('Roles:', member.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join(' | '), true)
```

The other properties will still use `user`, but `.roles` will be related to the GuildMember.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion to use 'GuildMember' worked. <3 :D

Comment: Happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 2):

try adding this `.addField("Roles:", member.roles.map(roles =>`${roles}`).join(', '), true)`

My whole code for this is

```
let user;
if (message.mentions.users.first()) {
    user = message.mentions.users.first();
} else {
    user = message.`enter code here`author;
}

const member = message.guild.member(user);

const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
    .addField(`${user.tag}`, `${user}`, true)
    .addField("ID:", `${user.id}`, true)
    .addField("Nickname:", `${member.nickname !== null ? `${member.nickname}` : 'None'}`, true)
    .addField("Status:", `${user.presence.status}`, true)
    .addField("In Server", message.guild.name, true)
    .addField("Game:", `${user.presence.game ? user.presence.game.name : 'None'}`, true)
    .addField("Bot:", `${user.bot}`, true)
    .addField("Joined The Server On:", `${moment.utc(member.joinedAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")}`, true)
    .addField("Account Created On:", `${moment.utc(user.createdAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")}`, true) 
    .addField("Roles:", member.roles.map(roles => `${roles}`).join(', '), true)
    .setFooter(`Replying to ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)
message.channel.send({embed});
```

Answer (score 0):

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined** - this means that somewhere in your code happening a situation of execution `.map` function of `undefined` variable.

You have only one `map`. Here:

```
   .addField('Roles:', user.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join(' | '), true)
                               // ^^^
```

This line trows this error, so this means that `user.roles` is `undefined`.

Try to:

```
let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
console.log(user.roles); // it is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Propably `user.roles` is `undefined`.

If it's ok that user has no roles, you can replace:

```
.addField('Roles:', user.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join(' | '), true)
```

with:

```
.addField('Roles:', user.roles ? user.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join(' | ') : "", true)
```

This will set empty string in case when there's no `roles` property in `user` object.

Another option is to set `user.roles` to empty array if it doesn't exist (or do something else in this `if`, i.e. throw error):

```
let user = /* get user*/
if (!user.roles){
    user.roles = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For roles i also suggest you to remove the `@everyone` role

Here are an example

```js
message.member.roles.cache.map(r => r.name)

// ["Mod","Member","Staff","Owner","@everyone"]
// If you don't want the everyone role use :

message.member.roles.cachemap(r => r.name).slice(0,-1).

// ["Mod","Member","Staff","Owner"]
```

So the roles field would be :

```js
.addField("Roles", member.roles.cache.map(r => '`'+r.name+'`').join(' - '), true)
```

Answer (score -1):

this is working 100% for discord.js 12.x

```
 <@&${message.guild.member(message.author)._roles.join('> <@&')}>
```