# My embed shows 'Undefined' for user roles on my user info command

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord.js

I am making a discord bot, and I decided to add a user info command. I did so, but the problem is that the `.setThumbnail` command is not working (so I can't see the picture) and that I want to display the roles of my members, which I did by using the `member.roles` function. But, it says in the embed 'undefined', here is my code for reference. I tried using only user but still gives me undefined under the User Roles on the embed.  Thanks in advance to whoever answers it!

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
var user = message.mentions.users.first();
var member = message.mentions.users.first(user);
if(!args[1]) return message.reply('Apologies! Please specify a particular member!');
    embed.setTitle('User Information')
    embed.addField('Username', user.username)
    embed.addField('User ID', user.id)
    embed.addField('User Tag', user.tag)
    embed.addField('User Roles', member.roles)
    embed.setColor(0x00FF93)
    embed.setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL)
    embed.setFooter('Generated by Salty!')
 message.channel.send(embed);
 break;
```

Comment: Also, how do I add to this command to show when the member joined Discord and if they are playing a game, the user info command shows this. In short, I need to fix:

1) The thumbnail not appearing.
2) The roles showing as 'undefined'

What I would like to add in this command:

1) When did a member join Discord.
2) If they are playing a game, I would like the command to show it. 

Side note: This must work for all members and not only for me. Thank you so much to whoever takes care of these! <3

Answer (score 1):

In discord.js v12.x, `user.displayAvatarURL` is a function.
Visit [this link](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL) for more information...

```
embed.setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL())
```

Also, `member.roles` is a manager, to get the roles of a member use `member.roles.cache`. This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253350/how-to-show-roles-of-user-discord-js-userinfo-command)

```
.addField('Roles:', member.roles.cache.map(r => `${r}`).join(' | '))
```

For the account creation you can get the timestamp with `user.createdAt`

```
.addField('Created at:', moment.utc(user.createdAt).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss'))
```

Hope this help !

Comment: Thank you so much! But, another favor to ask, if they are playing a game, how can I show that as well? Sorry if I am asking too much. Also, can you fix the thumbnail problem, for some reason, it is not appearing, thank you so so much Rakox! <3

Comment: Also Rakox, I have another problem, it says embed.addField('Roles:', member.roles.cache.map(r => `${r}`).join(' | ')), TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' 
of undefined. Please help. I am new to this, thanks! <3

Comment: Also, I am getting a reference error, moment is not defined. Please help. Thank you so so so much!!!!! <3

Comment: I got the thumbnail, but the above 3 comments need help. Thanks!!!! <3