# How to access Discord.js message's author's role?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to access the `roles` Collection by the `message` object because I need to get the `author`'s role. So far I tried the following:

`message.member.roles` and `message.guild.roles`

In both cases, I get an error: `guild` and `member` are `null`.

How am I supposed to access the `roles` Collection?

Comment: Can you please post the code for your message event?

Comment: About accessing member's roles, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253350/how-to-show-roles-of-user-discord-js-userinfo-command).

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the issue. The error was happening because I was trying to execute the command in a Direct Message and Roles are not defined in a DM. Roles are only defined in a server channel.