# Discord.js User Info Command

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I'm making a user info command for my bot in **discord.js**  and I don't now how to get the roles of a user. I tried looking up the discord.js documentation but I couldn't find anything.I already have the user with this code:

```
const {SlashCommandBuilder} = require('discord.js');
let user;
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('user')
        .setDescription('Display info about a selected user')
        .addUserOption(option => option.setName('target').setDescription('The user\'s information to show')),
    async execute(interaction) {
        user = interaction.options.getUser('target');

        if (user) {
            createEmbed(interaction)
        }
    },
};



function createEmbed(interaction) {

    const embed = {
        // other code
        fields: [


            {
                name: 'Roles',
                value: 'what goes here',
            }

        ],

        //other code
    }

    interaction.reply({
        embeds: [embed]
    })

    return;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

```
        user = interaction.options.getUser('target');
        member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
        roles = member.roles.cache.map(r => `${r}`).join(' , ')
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in :[How to show roles of user discord.js / userinfo command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253350/how-to-show-roles-of-user-discord-js-userinfo-command) You should use `map.`

```js
let member = interaction.member;
let roles = member.roles.cache.map(r => `${r}`).join(' , '))

    const embed = {
        fields: [


            {
                name: 'Roles',
                value: `${roles}`,
            }

        ],

    }

    interaction.reply({
        embeds: [embed]
    })
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick reply! I get  "TypeError: member.roles.map is not a function" when I run my command.

Comment: Hi, I edited the code. check it again. I forgot to place `.cache` for member roles

Comment: Hi! I just get "application did not respond".

Answer (score -1):

```
const GetUserData = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(USER_ID);
console.log(GetUserData.roles.cache);
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache